# Matching strings where multiple capture groups must be different in regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that picks out a boolean algebra identity, specifically ((A+B).(A+C)), where A, B and C are different strings consisting of characters [A-Z].
I am running into problems getting the regular expression recognise that in the string I am looking for A != B != C.
Here is what I have tried:

- `\(\(([A-Z]+)\+([A-Z])\)\.\(\1\+([A-Z])\)\)`

however, even though I have put every string that I want to be different in a capturing group, it doesn't stop it from thinking that strings B and C are the same. This is because the regular expression matches for all three of the following strings:

- ((A+B).(A+C))
- ((A+B).(A+A))
- ((A+A).(A+A))

while I only want it to match the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [negative lookahead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-21) to make sure that group 2 is not the same as group 1, and that group 3 is not the same as either groups 1 or 2.

```regex
\(\(([A-Z]+)\+(?!\1)([A-Z])\)\.\(\1\+(?!\1)(?!\2)([A-Z])\)\)
```

Split up for readability:

```regex
\(\(
([A-Z]+)
\+
(?!\1)([A-Z])
\)\.\(
\1
\+
(?!\1)(?!\2)([A-Z])
\)\)
```

Inputs:

```
((A+B).(A+C))
((A+B).(A+A))
((A+A).(A+A))
((A+B).(A+B))
```

Matches:

```
((A+B).(A+C))
```

[Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/flihNL/1)